# Highlight the sorted column

Tags: user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

I'm firing the databound event but I'm not sure what do do from there.
The links here lead to generic docs: 
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/highlight-sorted-column.aspx

Does anyone have a simple example of highlighting the current sorted column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is as follows:

1. Handle the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event of the grid.
2. Get the current sort expression of the [data source](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#fields-dataSource) using its [sort](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-sort) method.
3. Find the grid column which is bound to the sorted field. Iterate over the grid [columns](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#fields-columns) field.
4. Highlight the table cells which correspond to the column index. Use the [tbody](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#fields-tbody) field of the grid.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [ 
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    sortable: true,
    dataBound: function() {
      var columns = this.columns;
      var sort = this.dataSource.sort()[0];

      var sortedIndex = -1;

      if (sort) {
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          if (columns[i].field == sort.field) {
            sortedIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if (sortedIndex >= 0) {
        this.tbody
            .find("tr")
            .find("td:eq(" + sortedIndex + ")")
            .css( { background: "#a0b0c0" } );
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

And a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ixahid/1/edit

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.